# merge options from two Python functions

Tags: python

I am writing a Python wrapper script for another python function which takes command line options using optparse, say `-p` and `-i`. In my wrapper function I'd like to add some other command line options that are not defined in the external function, e.g. `-x`. I am looking for a way to combine the the options defined in the external function with the ones I define in the wrapper. The external scripts has a function like this:

```
def extparser():
    from optparse import OptionParser
    parser = OptionParser(
        prog="external-prog",
        usage="%prog [options]")

    parser.add_option(
        "-p", "--parameter", type="int", default=1,
        help="algo parameter")

    parser.add_option(
        "-i", "--iterations", type="int",
        help="number of iterations")

    (opts, args) = parser.parse_args()
    return opts
```

I can't change the code in the external function. In my wrapper script I have something like :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from extprog import extparser

def newparser():
    from optparse import OptionParser
    parser = OptionParser(
        prog="newprog",
        usage="%prog [options]")

    parser.add_option(
        "-x", "--extraparam", type="int",
        help="another parameter")

    return parser.parse_args()

if __name__=="__main__":
    extparser()
    newparser()
```

Now, of course this doesn't work as expected :

```
[myhost]>./sotest.py -x 1 -p 2 -i 3

Usage: external-prog [options] <action> <name>

external-prog: error: no such option: -x
```

Is there a way to ignore the error from the external program? The real list of options in the external program is pretty long and I want to avoid copying it into the wrapper script.

Comment: So you can't change the external function at all? Could you, perhaps , duplicate the file and modify it to suit your own needs? Just an idea.

Comment: No, I can't modify the external function. I could duplicate, but that's exactly what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to avoid getting that error while the external scripts optparse code is being called. What you can do is use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to control which variables you pass to the external script by invoking it manually.

E.g:

```
subprocess.call(["external-prog", "-p", "some p value", "-i", "10"])
```